# Why raise exceptions in python 3?

Tags: exception, python-3.7, raise

Why do we raise exceptions? Can't we use print with sys.exit() ?
The latter will do the same thing. Is there's something I'm missing?
 Do "raise" only help while defining a function , so that it won't return "None" in case of failure?
Examples would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: You can't catch `sys.exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are already multiple good answers on Quora:

https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-need-to-raise-exception-in-Python-programming-Cant-we-handle-the-same-thing-with-just-if-else-statements

Comment: Thanks for the answer Simon. I read those , they're informative. But my question is a bit different , I asked how is raise different ? We could use 'print' to show what's wrong and "sys.exit()" to terminate the program , after all raise will too terminate the program. Is it just a matter of simplicity?

Comment: You could do a sys.exit(), however many times you do not want to exit the program. For example: you are building a web browser showing an image and text, you can use try (load image) except to load the image. If it fails, the text is still displayed.